# Отображение сайта в Opera Mini

Tags: html, css

Есть проблема. Пишу CSS/HTML код рамки. Если зайти с компьютера, то рамка отобразится (что вполне логично), если же зайти на сайт с опера мини в мобильном виде, то соответственно она не отобразится. Как сделать так, чтобы рамки отображались?

Comment: Пробовали атрибут media указывать? Например:
`<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all, handled">`

Answer (score 1):

В мобильном виде все лишнее убирается, ничего не поделать

Comment: Дайте хоть код нам